# How to bootstrap providers in angular2

Tags: angular

I am using rc2,here i have a ts called config and i want that throught my app,for that i bootsrtapped in in my main.ts as

```
bootstrap(MyDemoApp, [  
provideForms(),
disableDeprecatedForms(),
APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,Navbar,
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },

HTTP_PROVIDERS,Config,(-Here it is-)
provide(ToastOptions, { useValue: new ToastOptions(options) }),
```

]);

I am using that here,

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import { IDetails } from '../interface';
 import { Config } from '../headers';

@Injectable()
  export class GetAllList {
   header:any;
   str = localStorage.getItem('social');
   loc = JSON.parse(this.str);
   id = this.loc.profile_id;
  constructor(private _http: Http,public config:Config) {
   this.header = this.config.header;
   }

   private _productUrl = this.header+'profile/editProfile/' + this.id;


   getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
   // console.log(this.id);
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => {
         return <IDetails[]>response.json().data[0];
        });

     }
  }
```

but i am not geeting any thing to my form,am i done mistake in bootstrapping?Can any one pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

```
ToastOptions,
```

instead of

```
provide(ToastOptions, { useValue: new ToastOptions(options) }),
```

should do

Comment: Gunter,actually there is mistake with my injectable class ,the server call itself is not going and when i print   private _productUrl it shows "undefinedprofile/editProfile/1"   so header is nopt getting appended to it

Comment: I would need to see more code (where you print it for example).

Comment: i printed in the getlist function

Comment: So where did you print it?

Comment: i printed inside the getlist() function

Comment: Gunter,how can i refresh my form just after submitting

Comment: I don't know. This doesn't seem to be related to providers.
I think you should move procedural code for initializing variables into the constructor (`localstorage.getItem()`, `json.parse()` and only declare the properties outside of the constructor, but I don't know such TS details very well (I use only Dart locally).